# Is it a good idea to run Stack Overflow as a service desk system?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, licensing

I'm using OTRS as my company helpdesk. It works great but for one of my customers which is not a well-payed. I decided to set up the Stack Overflow system as their service desk.

Is it a good idea?

And how much is it customizable? (Especially its calendar.)

Comment: Do you ever think that it is Open Source or just a Sign Up service to get it your own?

Comment: As an aside: what's wrong with the calendar?

Comment: @Arjan, I want to use it in my local region calendar which is not Georgian, it is loonier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not license our engine -- the only way to create public sites on this engine is through the open, democratic community process at http://area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: you mean that I'm not allowed to do it?

Comment: @Nasser, you're not *able* to use the SE engine.

Comment: @Nasser there are [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267) that you can use